# C Programming: Initialize pointer to char array inside a function

Tags: c, string, function, pointers

I need help with initializing a pointer to char array ***inside another function.***

I'm passing a **char array** and **pointer to char array** to a function.
I would like to copy characters from variable 'word' to 'secret' by address/reference/pointer.

I was able to do it by passing values to a function like this:

```
char    *set_secret(char *word, char *secret)
{
    int     i;

    for (i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (word[i] == ' ')
            secret[i] = ' ';
        else
            secret[i] = SECRET_SYMBOL;
    }
    secret[i] = '\0';

    return(secret);
}
```

How can I do to copy characters **into the pointer of char array by reference** ?

---

Here's what I have (have checked malloc, it's all good):

**SOURCE:**

```
void    init_secret(const char *word, char **secret)
{
    int     i;
    *secret = NULL;
    *secret = (char*)malloc( sizeof(char) * strlen(word) + 1 );

    // trying changing secret value by reference and not by value (copy)
    for (i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (word[i] == ' ')
            *secret[i] = ' ';
        else
            *secret[i] = '_';
    }
    *secret[i] = '\0';
}

int     main(void)
{
    char    *str = "TALK TO THE HAND";
    char    *secret = NULL;

    init_secret(str, &secret);
    printf("Secret word: %s\n", secret);

    return(0);
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Bus error: 10
```

Comment: [Please don't cast the result of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply index on `*secret`:

```
(*secret)[i]
```

or use a char* help variable:

```
char* s = *secret; ...
```

Comment: Could you explain how it works ? I really thought *secret[i] was it.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteBouhier `*` has lower precedence than `[]`. Also consider only assigning your string literals to `char const*`, and cranking up your compiler warnings.

Comment: @Quentin like gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror file.c ? Which flags would you suggest ?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteBouhier `-Wwrite-strings` to be specific, or `-std=*` with one of the standards. Albeit I'm genuinely surprised that the default (gnu89 I believe) does not raise the warning.